# Oracle and Apache - Aborting Requests

Tags: php, oracle, apache

Im running on a VM with CentOS and Oracle 11.2g XE.

I created a system that fetches Data from the Oracle DB (contains about 600K records) and displays them accordingly.

As i was optimizing the query and performance, i noticed that if i cancel my HTTP requests (Safari), i still see the session active in Oracle and is still running.

Now my questions:

1. Is this normal behavior?
2. Is there a way to tell oracle to stop a session once the HTTP request is cancelled?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

GhostGambler link was the answer.

I added a "if (connection_aborted () != 0) " inside the fetch loop for my database and queries were aborted successfully.